# Set $mysqli as a global variable for OOP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

Ok,
This is sort of an involved problem, but any help or advice would be incredibly appreciated.

So I'm working with a site that (using `.htaccess`) redirects all traffic to a `load.php`. For any `sql` functionality, I have an abstract class that has a lot of query statements as functions that pass parameters to define the specifics of each query.

e.g.
$table->update("constraints")

I'm trying to figure out how to set the connection to the database on `load.php`, and then set the connection as a variable (`$mysqli`) that can then be referenced in my abstract query class without having to pass the parameter to every single query function call.

Again, any help or advice would be appreciated.

Here's an example of a function:

```
 function clearTable (){
    $mysqli = dbConnect::connect();
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE $this->tablename";
    $mysqli->query($sql);

}
```

If I connect to the database in a construct function and set `$this->mysqli` and replace `$mysqli = dbConnect::connect();` with `$mysqli = $this->mysqli`, none of the queries work. Though they work with a fresh reconnect on each call.

Comment: `function __construct($conn) { $this->$mysqli = $conn; }` then use `$this->$mysqli` in your functions? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Some code might help with better answers.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: You did something wrong. Show us how you tried to implement this and we just might be able to help you correct it.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: That's not the suggestion that @AbraCadaver gave. Test his suggestion and you'll be set. It's called _"dependency injection"_ and it's the way to go.

Comment: Ok, yeah that's true, 
So what is $conn?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So currently, the abstract class is extended for each table, Is there a better way to do that? Granted, opening a connection each table is far better than each query, but still not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Dependency Injection for this.

Basically it means that the class that needs the database connection doesn't create the connection, it just receives the already instasiated instance.

#### Example

In some init file:

```
// Create the db connection
$db = new Mysqli(......);

// Pass it to the query class that needs it
$queryClass = new QueryClass($db);
```

Then in your class file:

```
class QueryClass
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        // $this->db will now be the same Mysql instance
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function doSomeQuery()
    {
        $this->db->query(....);
    }
}
```

A bonus for this is that you don't need to touch the QueryClass, if you ever want to start making some unit tests. You only need to pass a DB connection to a test database instead.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through this a bit more, I can also create my `db::connect()` function to look like this:

```
class dbConnect {
    private static $db;
    private $mysqli;
    private function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    }
    function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
    public static function connect() {
        if (self::$db == null) {
            self::$db = new dbConnect();
        }
        return self::$db->mysqli;
    }
}
```

and pass that as `$this->mysqli` in the query functions file

Comment: How you create the database connection isn't that important, as long as you still pass the mysqli instance to the classes that needs it. If you were to call `dbConnect::connect()` from other classes, you have made a hard dependency, which is considered bad practice, since you can't change the database connection without changing your class implementations.

Comment: That sort of makes sense. Aren't class implementations supposed to be less general and more specialized (therefore needing to be changed anyway if you needed to change your database connection)? I guess, in my mind, it should look like db.config.php is fed into db.connect.php into sql.function.php. In that instance, you would really only touch db.config for a new project, and extend sql.function.php into new instantiations for each use...

Comment: You've got the main idea. :) All though, usually, you would send the db config to the db class (like you said), so you only need to use another conf, if you want to reuse your db class with another connection. No need to extend it if the methods are the same, just with another conf. You should look into IoC-containers and Interfaces. That will help you with all of this. :)

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. Thanks!